# How to use jars in an Eclipse library for eclipse annotation processor?

Tags: eclipse, ivy, apt

I want to use the annotation processor that comes with the [Ollie library](https://github.com/pardom/Ollie) in `Eclipse`.

Hopefully, the annotation processor is available in the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.michaelpardo/ollie-compiler/0.3.1).

Using `Ivy` with the [Ivyde Eclipse plugin](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/index.html), you can define a [separate Eclipse jar library](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/create.html) that has only the compiler binaries easily by creating a separate ivy file (named here `ivy-compile.xml`).

Which is convenient in case the annotation processing tool has many dependencies.

[image: second container]

The issue is that Eclipse doesn't let me pick the jar from an Eclipse library. Only from a real folder.

[image: jars]

**Is there a way to tell eclipse to use the jars in the `ivy-compile.xml` container?**

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990697/can-ivy-or-ivyde-add-related-jars-into-java-build-path-library-automatically-in) might help you :

> You'll need to add the IVY runtime to the build path of the project. This can be done via Project Properties->Java Build Path under the Libraries tab, select Add Library then select IvyDE Managed Dependencies.
>
> Once that's done, an Ivy resolve will add all the jars specified in ivy.xml to the project's build path.